# Unity Line Vector Calculation

Tags: algorithm, math, unity-game-engine, vector, geometry

Let's suppose we have two position vectors **a** and **b**, where a is the base for a line:
**g: x = a + r*d (d being the direction of the line)**

We can be sure that **b** lies on **g** due to my game generation algorithm. Then my question is how can I find **r**?

The problem seems to be with the result being always positive, when calculating the length and then checking how often **d** fits  the result will always be positive, and therefore only partly correct.

My other idea was to calculate it by **a + r * d = b <=> r = (b - a) / d** . But unity doesn't allow vector division. 
Thank you in advance for any help, maybe I am just being stupid at some point. Sorry

Comment: Could you draw and show a sketch describing your problem? It is not quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g is your result, a is your start point.

```
  r = (g -a ).magnitude;
```

Use dot(d, (g-a)) to know whether positive or negative.

Comment: What does .magnitude do? isnt it the length?

Comment: Yes, and this is what you want there. At least, this is what i understand.

Comment: Since https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html says its only the length

Comment: But wont this always be positive, if we take the square root?

Comment: How can i determine between positive and negative r's?

Comment: You can use d and do a dot product. If dot(d, (g-a)) is positive then r is. Else r is negative.

Comment: Actually that dot product is your answer I realize...it will give you how much of there is on g-a.

Comment: Maybe u can edit ur answer, than ill vote it as answer :P

Comment: Are u real good in maths? Cause i have a problem, which i am not being able to solve for 4 monhts :D u wanna try?

Comment: Post another question, this is how you should do in SO.